# How to set yarn version for a specific project

Tags: yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces, yarn-v2, yarnpkg-v2

I have 2 projects which I need to run parallely on my local machine. Problem is, one of the project is using Yarn 3 and other one is using Yarn 1.

Steps given on Yarn's website https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/install, sets the version globally, due to which only one project runs at a time and other one fails.

Can somebody please help me configure yarn version to specific project?